# Not well formed: Element type "xs:element" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am getting an error saying *Not well formed: Element type "xs:element" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".* All my element tags are nested properly though. No matter what I do, I am still getting the error.

This is my xsd file. I was given an xml file, and asked to develop an xsd file for it.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="createSalesOrder">
  <xs:complexType minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="order">
  <xs:complexType> 
   <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   
    <xs:element name="orderSource">
     <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="purchaseOrder">
    <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="purchaseOrderType">
    <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="purchaseOrderType">
    <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:date"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
     <xs:element name="orderType">
    <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="orderExpiry">
    <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
     <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
  <xs:maxInclusive value="5"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="orderConsumerReferenceId">
    <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="orderSourceReferenceId">
    <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
  <xs:pattern value="\d{8}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="shipping">
     <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="requestedDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    <xs:element name="shipmentOrigin" type="xs:boolean"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="orderCurrency">
     <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="currenyCode" type="xs:string" default="EUR"/>
    <xs:element name="currencyExchangeRate" type="xs:integer">
     <xs:simpleType minOccurs="1">
      <xs:restriction>
    <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
   </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="partner">
     <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="partnerRole" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="partnerId"/>
    <xs:element name="communicationLanguageCode" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:all>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string">
    <xs:restriction>
     <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="salesOrganization">
     <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="distributionChannel">
     <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z]"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="division">
     <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:maxLength value="2"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="orderTerm" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="lineItem" minOccurs="0">
     <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="lineId" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="parentLineId">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="12"/>
   </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="materialFlowType type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="material" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="materialDescription" minOccurs="0">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
   </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="orderedQuantity" minOccurs="1" type="xs:integer"/> 
    <xs:element name="configuration">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="instanceId">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
       <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="parentInstanceId">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
       <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="quantity" value="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="objectKey">
     <xs:simpleKey>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleKey>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="characteristics" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="1">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="1">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction value="xs:string">
       <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="price">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:maxlength value="15"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:element name="currencyCode" type="xs:string" default="EUR" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction>
       <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="shippingDate">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:dateTime"/>
   </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="shipmentOrigin" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="callBackUrl" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element> 
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double quote missing in the following line

```
<xs:element name="materialFlowType type="xs:integer"/>
```

Correct code

```
<xs:element name="materialFlowType" type="xs:integer"/>
```

You have some additional error with the xsd file.
In a xs:complexType tag xs:element is not allowed.
You need to wrap entire "order" element with xs:sequence tag like this

```
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="order">.....</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate error is due to a missing closing quote on an attribute.

Change

```
<xs:element name="materialFlowType type="xs:integer"/>
```

to

```
<xs:element name="materialFlowType" type="xs:integer"/>
```

Be aware, however, that you have a slew of additional errors to correct.  I would not post the entire sequence without first exerting considerable effort in fixing them yourself.